# Liang Barsky line clipping algorithm with polygonal clipping area

Tags: c++, polygon, clipping

I searched the Internet for ways to trim the line with polygon in 2D... but unsuccessfully. Could you please help?

My problem is in title. I need to clip line with polygonal clipping area. In cpp if it is possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Clipping a line to a polygon](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/cliplinetopoly/).  Are you sure you want to use Liang Barsky to clip to a polygon?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. We learnd it, but I do not know how to implement it. Cohen-Sutherland is much simpler.